# Regex pattern to match certain url

Tags: java, regex

I have a large text and I only want to use certain information from it. The text looks like this:

```
Some random text here
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8
More random text here
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_1_av.m3u8
More random text here
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_2_av.m3u8
More random text here
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_3_av.m3u8
```

I only want the http text. There are several of them in the text but I only need one of them. The regular expression should be "starts with http and ends with .m3u8".

I looked at the glossary of all the different expression but it is very confusing to me. I tried `"/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{12,30})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/"` as my pattern. But is that enough?

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: There are 4 that start with http and end with .m3u8...You want to match all 4?

Comment: @brso05 No, only 1 of them.

Comment: Your regex won't match any of the above.

Comment: why you didn't add .m3u8 at the end of your pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text is line-separated at every line representation in your example, here's a snippet that will work:

```
String text = 
"Some random text here" +
System.getProperty("line.separator") +
"http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8" +
System.getProperty("line.separator") +
"More random text here" +
System.getProperty("line.separator") +
"http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8" +
System.getProperty("line.separator") +
// removed some for brevity
"More random text here" +
System.getProperty("line.separator") +
// added counter-example ending with "NOPE"
"http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.NOPE";

// Multi-line pattern:
//                           ┌ line starts with http
//                           |    ┌ any 1+ character reluctantly quantified
//                           |    |  ┌ dot escape
//                           |    |  |  ┌ ending text
//                           |    |  |  |   ┌ end of line marker
//                           |    |  |  |   |
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^http.+?\\.m3u8$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8
http://xxx-f.xxx.net/i/xx/open/xxxx/1370235-005A/EPISOD-1370235-005A-xxx_,892,144,252,360,540,1584,xxxx,.mp4.csmil/index_0_av.m3u8
```

**Edit**

For a refined "filter" by the `"index_x"` file of the URL, you can simply add it in the `Pattern` between the protocol and ending of the line, e.g.:

```
Pattern.compile("^http.+?index_0.+?\\.m3u8$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect. I also forgot that the different links have different indexes. The one I want is index_1.

Comment: You can fine-tune the `Pattern` with something like: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^http.+?index_1.+?\\.m3u8$", Pattern.MULTILINE);`. That will "filter" by `index_`.

Comment: Your ^http.+?index_0.+?\\.m3u8$ did not work but ^(http://.*\.m3u8)$ did work. How can I add index_1 to the "^(http://.*\.m3u8)$". Thank you!

Comment: Ehm. Replace the `index_0` part with `index_1`?

Comment: I did. Did not math at all. Tried it with: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: Try it in java instead. if you use the new `Pattern` from my answer's edit, applied to the example in my answer (i.e. `indfex_0` text), it **will** match.

Comment: Thanks. The indexes are dynamic, sometimes the largest one is index_6 and sometimes index_1. Can I make it dynamics o it only takes the last math in the string?

Comment: @SandeepSingh you can use `index[035]` as an idiom to get indices `0`, `3` and `5` for instance.

Comment: The indexes are from 0-8. Sometimes we get 0-2, 0-6 or only 0. I want the regex to find the last math and print it to me, regardless of indexes.

Comment: When I use index[035], I get no math. Thank you for your help Mena!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but this should do the trick:

```
^(http:\/\/.*\.m3u8)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect. I also forgot that the different links have different indexes. The one I want is index_1.

Answer (score 0):

It is the answer of @capnibishop, but with a little change.

```
^(http://).*(/index_1)[^/]*\.m3u8$
```

Added the missing "$" sign at the end. This ensures it matches

```
http://something.m3u8
```

and not

```
http://something.m3u81
```

Added the condition to match **index_1** at the end of the line, which means it wil match:

```
http://something/index_1_something_else.m3u8
```

and not

```
http://something/index_1/something_else.m3u8
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! One problem though... I am getting an error in Eclipse. "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )".

Comment: How do you get the error? at runtime? during compilation? Are you using Java? How are you using the regular expression?